# AppStore Checking for updates.. consuming massive amounts of memory

Tags: macos, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, memory, software-update

Is this normal? (softwareupdated is an apple helper checking for updates)

[image: Softwareupdated consuming 36gb memory]

I restarted my mac and it started again

slowly climbing the numbers

The AppStore is spinning trying to check for updates, and i am unable to update my mac >.<

[image: Appstore Image]

So i guess my actual question is

Can it be fixed? Do i need to reinstall Yosemite or can it be resolved with a simple Patch without going through AppStore?

Specs: 
[image: MacSpecs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I force quitted the 'softwareupdated'-helper
and immediatly tried to click the update button, before AppStore began to check for updates.
Took a few tries but managed to get pass the check and have now Succesfully updated to 10.10.4

Answer (score 0):

[OSXDaily.com wrote up a helpful article about this very same issue.](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/01/fix-frozen-app-store-updates-and-high-softwareupdated-cpu/)